# scraping data from a website node js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

i am new to scraping data from a website, i would like to scrape the level number from: https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/pc/Twitch.BadGuyBen, i have tried using cheerio and request for this task and im not sure if im using the right selector maybe some tips on what i should do. this is my code:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var options = {
    url: `https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/pc/Twitch.BadGuyBen`,
    method: 'GET'
}

request(options, function (error, response, body) {    
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    var level = "";
    var xp = "";

    $('.top-stats').filter(function(){

        var data = $(this);
        level = data.children().first().find('.value').text();

        console.log(level);
    })
});
```

again i am not sure if i have even selected the right class much appreciated.

EDIT:

also '.top-stats' is present further on

[website open in chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1mMm.png)

[other .top-stats class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBWNs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `request` to get the body since the stats are displayed using javascript. You will have to use something like [`puppeteer`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to request the page and execute the javascript and then scrape the stats.